# Ошибка дубликатов Android Studio

Tags: android, unity3d, gradle

`Error:Execution failed for task ':transformClassesWithJarMergingForRelease'. > com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: com/kidoz/sdk/api/BuildConfig.class`

Пересмотрел весь проект, дубликатов библиотеки нету, файлы BuildConfig есть в jar kidoz, в директориях

`KidozSdk\build\generated\source\buildConfig\debug\com\kidoz\sdk\api\BuildConfig.java`

и

`KidozSdk\build\generated\source\buildConfig\release\com\kidoz\sdk\api\BuildConfig.java`

Пробовал комментировать файл который в папке debug, при синхронизации восстанавливается в прежний вид, пробовал удалять, ошибка:

`Error:Execution failed for task :KidozSdk:generateDebugAndroidTestBuildConfig`
`> java.io.IOException: Could not delete path E:\A_Project\BabyShapes_SDK10InstantApp\Export\Happy Kids Baby Shapes 2-5\KidozSdk\build\generated\source\buildConfig\androidTest\debug\com\kidoz\sdk`

kidoz это рекламная сеть
Помогите разобраться как еще можно определить дубликаты библиотек, классов, что не так делаю

Библиотеки

```
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
compile project(':KidozSdk')

compile(name: 'play-services-ads-11.6.0', ext:'aar')
compile(name: 'play-services-ads-lite-11.6.0', ext:'aar')
compile(name: 'play-services-basement-11.6.0', ext:'aar')
compile(name: 'play-services-gass-11.6.0', ext:'aar')
compile(name: 'support-compat-25.2.0', ext:'aar')
compile(name: 'support-core-ui-25.2.0', ext:'aar')
compile(name: 'support-core-utils-25.2.0', ext:'aar')
compile(name: 'support-fragment-25.2.0', ext:'aar')
compile(name: 'support-media-compat-25.2.0', ext:'aar')
compile(name: 'support-v4-25.2.0', ext:'aar')


compile project(':adcolony')
compile project(':appodeal')
compile project(':GoogleMobileAdsPlugin')
compile project(':inmobi')



compile project(':play-services-ads-license-11.6.0')
compile project(':play-services-ads-lite-license-11.6.0')
compile project(':play-services-basement-license-11.6.0')
compile project(':play-services-gass-license-11.6.0')
compile project(':startapp')
compile project(':yandex-metrica')
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Открыл архивом jar KidozSDK и удалил файл BuildConfig.class